# Random element in a collection, JSP

Tags: jsp, loops

I need to iterate through a collection in a JSP. Right now I use a `<c:forEach>` loop which goes through every element in the collection. I just need to access the property of one, randomly selected element in the collection.

Any ideas on how to do this in JSP?

Comment: Does it need to be random, or can it be, say, the first? Is there a particular reason you want to do this on the JSP side as opposed to the Java side?

Comment: It has to be random and no I dont have to do it on the jsp side. I can do it on the java side. I was thinking of creating adding a request object containing the randomly selected element. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's what I'd do; I don't feel that kind of stuff should be in the JSP.